# I'm not able to upload or post more than 1 mb file in android

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

I have created a program in android for uploading files. Everything is working perfectly. But, when I upload a file that has more than 1Mb, I got this error from my server: "Error while Uploading"

Here is my UploadFile() method

```
 private void uploadFile() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Uploading File...", true);


        // Map is used to multipart the file using okhttp3.RequestBody
        Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
        long maxLength = 10000000;
        File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
        if(file.length() > maxLength){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "can't upload file if size more than 10mb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();

        }else {
            String name = tv_name.getText().toString();
            String email = tv_email.getText().toString();
            // Parsing any Media type file
            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
            RequestBody requestBody1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), name);
            RequestBody requestBody2 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), email);
            map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + selectedFilePath + "\"", requestBody);
            map.put("name\"; username=\"" + name + "\"", requestBody1);
            map.put("email\"; email=\"" + email + "\"", requestBody2);

            ApiConfig getResponse = AppConfig.getRetrofit().create(ApiConfig.class);
            Call<ServerResponse> call = getResponse.upload("token", map);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                    if(dialog.isShowing()){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    ServerResponse serverResponse = response.body();
                    if (serverResponse != null) {
                        if (serverResponse.getSuccess()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), serverResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), serverResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
//                    Log.v("Response", serverResponse.toString());
                    }
                   // dialog.dismiss();
                    goToProfile();


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

TimeOut

```
   OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
         .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
         .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
         .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();

return new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL).client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

}

It's My PHP Code

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file_name = $target_dir .basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$response = array();

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_FILES["file"])) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_name)) {
        $success = true;
        $message = "Successfully Uploaded";
     } else {
        $success = false;
        $message = "Error while uploading";
     }
} else {
        $success = false;
        $message = "Required Field Missing";
}

$response["success"] = $success;
$response["message"] = $message;
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Narrow it down. Try the PHP code from your browser or CURL.

Comment: same code here ... almost the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610385/my-progressdialog-is-not-disappearing ... please stop creating dummy accounts and posting the same question

Comment: http://shaoniiuc.com/android/image-upload-retrofit-library/

Comment: I used Both of Code  :  
http://shaoniiuc.com/android/image-upload-retrofit-library/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610385/my-progressdialog-is-not-disappearing

Answer (score 0):

Try to Compress the file and upload again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this configuration of retrofit:

```
public static OkHttpClient okHttpClient1 = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(150, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(150, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(150, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient1)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

in short, I mean to say, **increase** your timeout on Android side.

Comment: i have used it     public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {

         OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                 .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                 .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                 .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL).client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }